# Ignore field to select in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, model, eloquent

I'm using a database with images as blob data and I want to ignore the "image" field of the table/model by default but be able to use the field later. ¿Is this possible?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your model, for example `User` model:

```
protected $hidden = array('image');
```

If you use this:

```
$model = User::find(1);
dd($model->toArray());
```

You'll not see the `image` field but if you use this:

```
dd($model->image);
```

Then you'll see that.

Comment: This just stops the field being included in array or json representations. It does not stop a field being loaded by default, which is what you would want to do with a blob.

Comment: That's correct because OP wants to use it later so it must be loaded, what's wrong with this, can you explain @dhinchliff?

Comment: What is wrong is that you don't want to load the image field every time you load the model, only the times you use the field. It's a common mistake to believe that the `$hidden` array stops fields from being loaded, but it doesn't.

Comment: No, it's not a mistake, I know that this field will be loaded and that is required because the OP wants to use it so it's must be loaded, this answer shows how the OP can achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Have you ever read the question, specially `I want to ignore the "image" field of the table/model by default but be able to use the field later`, so this field should be loaded but could be ignored in some cases.

Comment: Also this answer is accepted because it satisfied the OP's requirement.

Comment: The OP is not asking how to ignore the field from array or json output, he's asking how to ignore it from the select. If it was the case that he was going to use this field every time he  selected it he would not be making the question. By `later` I understand that he wants to be able to reference the field in his code even if it was not loaded by default. Maybe the question is wrong, maybe he just wanted to filter the field for output. But the current answer does not match the current question.

Comment: Does the OP know the image is being loaded every time using this approach?

Comment: You just can't/shouldn't make your decision to mark an answer wrong depending on `maybe`, as long as I know that, this answer solves the problem/gives a solution to OP's question and there is nothing more but if that question were about how it works then I would have answered it that way.

Comment: I didn't mark it as wrong, it is still marked as correct.

Comment: Your down vote means that you disagree it as correct :-)

Comment: I do disagree, if the OP wanted to know how to hide a field from the array representation instead of from the select then the question needs to be edited. Even If the answer helped the OP if it does not match the question then it's wrong, it will confuse future readers.

Comment: I'll be watching this :-)